# How to reformat a string of string operations and get its result

Tags: python, string, format

I have written a code that aims to expand a string. For example:
`solve("3(ab)") = "ababab" -- "ab" repeats 3 times`

I managed to rewrite the input string into a more readable way. However, I haven't figured out a way to reformat this string such that python can execute the operation. I am unfamiliar with the .format methods.

````
def solve(st):    
    rewritten = ''

    for i in range(len(st)-1):    
        if st[i].isdigit():
            if st[i+1] == '(':
                rewritten += st[i] + '*' 
            else:
                rewritten += st[i]

        elif st[i].isalpha():
            if st[i+1] == '(' or st[i+1].isdigit():
                    rewritten += st[i] + '+'   
            else:
                rewritten += st[i]
        else:
            rewritten += st[i]

    rewritten += st[-1]      
    return rewritten

solve("k(a3(b(a2(c))))") #returns 'k+(a+3*(b+(a+2*(c))))', ideally 'kabaccbaccbacc'```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`eval` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) to evaluate your final `rewritten` string. You just have to rewrite chars with additional quotation marks:

```
>>> eval('"k"+("a"+3*("b"+("a"+2*("c"))))')
'kabaccbaccbacc'
```